# Plugin to add CordovaWebView

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I need to load a third party URL in my cordova application.

- I want to keep the cordovawebview of my main app open (hidden or in behind), so the users can immediately come back to my main application (without reload delay).
- I need to access cordova functionalities from external URL and communicate with my main app from the new page.

I did a quick research and implemented various methods, but yet not sure what is the way to go.

A. Using iFrame: looks like it is not 100% reliable (look at [this](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/iFrame-Usage))

B. Using InAppBrowser: Communication with my main app is my main concern here. Also not sure if I can call cordova functions from within InAppBrowser

C. I implemented [embedding a second CordovaWebView](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html) in my app (changing android native app). This solution looks good, but needs some changes in native android and ios apps (specially ios is what I want avoid getting involve with).

Is there any other method which I can try (to resolve mentioned drawbacks)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is actually a decent question, however, it does not fit the format of SO. We do not recommend external libraries (i.e. any plugins) and aside from that it would be based on opinions.

Comment: Thanks dirkk. I edited the last part of my question. Hopefully it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

Based on what you asked. I  recommend  [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools) for developing HTML5 based application.

What are the advantages?

1. XDK has a IDE(Brackets based) and whole building interface. you can build apps in multiple platform with just one click.
2. XDK fully support Cordova and its plugins if you want more access to device.
3. You do not need to know anything about Android and IOS coding, which you preferred.

If you want to embed the webview into native code, [crosswalk embedded mode](https://crosswalk-project.org/) is a good choose. You can use `EvaluateJavascript()` and `AddJavascriptInterface()` (Android for example) to communicate between native code and webview, but in this case you have to know some basic coding skill in each platform.

Comment: Thank you Summer. I will take a look and let you know.

Comment: Summer, Looks like crosswalk doesn't support iOS [link](https://crosswalk-project.org/#documentation/about/faq)

Comment: Yes, Crosswalk does not support IOS for now. You can use XDK (with cordova if you want) to develop both android and ios apps.